# Socket.io application is not getting deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I have created a basic chat server using nodejs, socket.io and express and I am trying it to deploy it from heroku using my git repo. When I open the herokuapp website for my app(https://obnerd-chat-app.herokuapp.com/), it shows something like this:

[image]

Here is my server.js file which is linked with main in package.json:

```js
//router for server
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
//server.listen(80);
var users = {};
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/app'))
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //serve our index.html
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('new-user', function(user){
  users[socket.id] = user.name
  console.log(users[socket.id] + " connected");
  socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', user)
  io.emit('user-online', 'There are currently '+Object.keys(users).length+' online')
})
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log(users[socket.id] + " disconnected");
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]
    io.emit('user-online', 'There are currently '+Object.keys(users).length+' online')
  })
})
 //divert again, emit message
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

and package.json

```js
{
  "name": "live-chat-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-static": "^0.7.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Please help me with this because I'm not so experienced with these 'deploying' things.

Comments, answers appreciated.

Comment: What do the logs say? If you run `heroku logs --tail -a APP_NAME` and then try to visit the app URL, the logs should give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got what was the error:

The package devDependencies accidentally contained nodemon and my `npm start` command was `nodemon server.js` so because nodemon got pruned away I couldn't deploy the app.

Fixed the issue by changing it to like this:
`start : node server.js` and everything is fine.

Check my [chat app](https://obnerd-chat-app.herokuapp.com) and give me some tips for its improvement. Thnak you.